# React query: invalidate multiple queries but wait until they all finished on mutation success

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-query

So I’m using React query and I have a mutation and I have a onSucess callback like this:

```
onSuccess: () => {
  return queryClient.invalidateQueries([FETCH_USER, userId]);
}
```

I want to invalidate another query, I know I can do this:

```
onSuccess: () => {     
    queryClient.invalidateQueries([FETCH_USER, userId]);
    queryClient.invalidateQueries([FETCH_USER_BOOKS, userId]);
}
```

But if I don’t use the return then it doesn’t wait for the invalidation and sets the mutation as done.

Is there a way to use the return for both invalidations?

Comment: `invalidateQueries` is a Promise, so you can just await them in your onSuccess handler

Comment: Not sure if it would work but what if you do () => Promise.all([
    queryClient.invalidateQueries([FETCH_USER, userId]),
    queryClient.invalidateQueries([FETCH_USER_BOOKS, userId])
])

Comment: Yeah I initially tried doing await query1; return query2; but this is better cause it makes no sense waiting for one call to finish, since they're independent.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

ideally, you would structure your query keys so that you can tackle them all in one invalidation:

```
[FETCH_USER, userId]
[FETCH_USER, userId, BOOKS]
```

then, you can target them with:

```
queryClient.invalidateQueries([FETCH_USER, userId])
```

this will fuzzily match all array keys that start have `FETCH_USER` at the first index and `userId` at the second, no matter what comes after them. That's why query keys should form a hierarchy if possible. I'm going into details here: https://tkdodo.eu/blog/effective-react-query-keys

---

if that is not possible, you can always wrap both promises in a `Promise.all` and return that:

```
onSuccess: () => Promise.all([    
    queryClient.invalidateQueries([FETCH_USER, userId]),
    queryClient.invalidateQueries([FETCH_USER_BOOKS, userId])
])
```